# Excel function to compare multiple columns and sum the results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tabs in excel. First one has Floors in column A and row 1 has Subjects (Doors, Windows etc.). Second tab has 3 columns, first one has Floor, second one has Subjects and the third one has the amount of said Subjects. I need a formula to check that the First columns match and if they do check the Subject cell and if it matches, add to sum. I tried two if statements but couldn't get the passing rows' 3rd column to sum.

Example of the format I need to work with

First tab where results should show up

[image]

Second tab containing the data

[image]

Comment: Did you try SUMIFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$C:$C,Sheet2!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet2!$B:$B,B$1)
```

Then copy over and down.

Where `Sheet2` is the name of your second tab.